# How to check which branch you are on with mercurial

Tags: mercurial, branch

What is the best way to check which branch I am on with mercurial?

```
hg log -l 5
```

This seems to show me the latest commits in the repo and not about working state as git would, so I'm looking for something like `git status` I suppose, which would tell me what branch I am on.  `hg status` doesn't show me anything.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use the `hg identify` command with the `-b` for branch option:

```
C:\Some\Repository> hg identify -b
default
```

Answer (score 28):

`hg branch`.  I suggest at least reading `hg help` once :^)

Answer (score 4):

```
$ hg branch
```

You can just always use the grep with a keyword to search.
In this case,

```
$ hg help | grep branch`
```

Gives you:

```
branch        set or show the current branch name  
branches      list repository named branches  
graft         copy changes from other branches onto the current branch  
heads         show branch heads
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `hg sum`

for example, say you have two branches, A and B

```
[root@B6LEB1 ATS]# hg update A
0 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
[root@B6LEB1 ATS]# hg sum 
parent: 1787:3f06e1a0260a 
 made A
branch: A
commit: (clean)
update: (current)
[root@B6LEB1 ATS]# hg update B
0 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
[root@B6LEB1 ATS]# hg sum
parent: 1788:7ff3c507efd9 tip
 made B
branch: B
commit: (clean)
update: (current)
```

Answer (score -1):

You also might want to specify the currently checked-out version explicitly. Then the output of `hg log` will return what you look for:

```
hg log -r.
```